# How to refresh a page after form submission with PHP mail-handler

Tags: php

After submitting data from a contact form via PHP mail-handler insructions, the entire page goes blank even though the email gets sent OK. Pressing the "F5" key refreshes the page but I would rather the system do that automatically instead of bothering the user.

I have tried using the header function immediately after the if(isset) line, as follows:

```
[code]
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  header("Location: https://amacwebsolutions.com");
}
[/code]
```

Am I putting the redirect code in the wrong place, or do I need an entirely different solution?

Here is the full PHP code:

```
[code]
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
        {
          header("Location: https://amacwebsolutions.com");
        }    
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $subject=$_POST['subject'];
        $msg=$_POST['msg']; 
        $to='info@amacwebsolutions.com';
        $subject="RE: ".$subject;
        $message="Name: ".$name."\n"."Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$msg;
        $headers="From: info@amacwebsolutions.com\r\nReply-To: $email"; 
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "<h1>Sent succesfully! Thank you,".$name." We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
        }  
            else {
               echo "Something went wrong!";
            }
    }
?>
[/code]
```

Comment: Yes, move your header redirection after the closing else bracket. and you don't need { } these brackets around header redirection

Comment: redirect after that `Sent succesfully!` text not before it. and use `exit()`;

Comment: is there any html output before calling `header`?

Comment: Thanks Danish Hakim Khan and Carl Binalla for your attempts. Unfortunately this hasn't worked after I moved the header function down below the if/then/else statement, and I also discarded the unnecessary curly braces.

Yes, RamRaider, the entire contact form along with PHP code is embedded inside an inner HTML page, as I didn't want this to be modal or popup.

Any further suggestions, guys.

Thanks,

Mister_Mack

Comment: Sorry guys... not working. I'm going to bone up on solving this with Javascript and Ajax.

Comment: Just an update for anyone who is interested... I stripped back much of my HTML to simplify the issue. I had my contact form embedded in an iframe within my 'contact.html' inner page. Suspecting this may be causing problems, I scrapped the iframe and placed the <form> tag straight into the HTML page. This ironed out a lot of gitches.

Still some glitches left, but I guess that's another problem for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by putting header in if condition.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg']; 
    $to='info@amacwebsolutions.com';
    $subject="RE: ".$subject;
    $message="Name: ".$name."\n"."Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$msg;
    $headers="From: info@amacwebsolutions.com\r\nReply-To: $email"; 
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "<h1>Sent succesfully! Thank you,".$name." We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
        header("Location: https://amacwebsolutions.com");
    } else {
           echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
}
```

Comment: Still not working... I corrected my URL to include the path to the contact page at
https://amacwebsolutions.com/_includes/contact.html (sorry, my fault!).
This makes no difference though, no matter where I place the header function. Is there some sort of 'redirect' code that might work more effectively?